# Pass table row values to struts action class which uses display: column tag

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I have a struts table which displays data using `<display:column>` tag.It has many rows and checkbox for each row. But for only one column I need to show as text fields which I did using `<display:column><input type ="text"..../></display:column>`. Now the problem is I need to submit only the value of the text fields for the rows which have been selected by checking the check box. The submit button is outside the display tag. Can anybody please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Write an onclick handler which takes the value of the input field and submits it.

Comment: Yes....I have a method onclick of button.But not sure how can I pass the value of each text field in the row to the action class.

Comment: When you submit the form values are passed with the request. Struts can handle these values if you bind them to the action.

Comment: Can you share some example please... Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15343980/1654265 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/15267703/1654265

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798118/how-can-i-get-checkbox-values-from-struts2-checkbox-in-displaytag-to-action-clas.